# python3.6 - TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes - but no files involved

Tags: python, subprocess

the following code returns an error and I don't understand why...
Running on Python 3.6

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def execute_shell_cmd(cmd):
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), b''):
                sys.stdout.write(c)
        for e in iter(lambda: process.stderr.read(1), b''):
                sys.stderr.write(e)

execute_shell_cmd("ls -l")
```

The error returned:
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Everything I see online talks about files and opening them with 'wb' options, but this is irrelevant here.

I'm sure it's silly...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're opening the subprocess without an encoding parameter set, so the streams are binary streams (which is an excellently sane default, considering e.g. something like GhostScript could output a binary PDF on `stdout`).

Do

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
   cmd,
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
   shell=True,
   encoding='utf-8',
   errors='strict',   # could be ignore or replace too, `strict` is the default
)
```

if you'd like the streams to be wrapped in an UTF-8 decoder so you get strings out of them, not bytes. Of course, this implies you know the output data is always UTF-8.

Comment: After reading your answer, I realized that this is the normal reaction, and what I was facing at first, is the un-normal behaviour (If you could reply there, that would be great!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485049/python-subprocess-contradiction-between-two-programs