# Subprocess contradiction between two programs:

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I know this may seem weird, but I'm trying to understand why the following happens:

I'm editing a Python program at work and when I run the following Python function:

```
def execute_shell_cmd(cmd):
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), b''): 
            print("type_c = ", type(c))
            sys.stdout.write(c)
        for e in iter(lambda: process.stderr.read(1), b''):
            sys.stdout.write(e)

execute_shell_cmd("ls -l")
```

I get in the output that type_c is "bytes" and sys.stdout.write(c) runs regularly and prints one byte at a time.

But when I run this function from a standalone program, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

How is that possible?

Comment: It probably depends on how `sys.stdout` is opened and/or configured, but you're not showing that part.

Comment: Where can it be configured? Is it just a code somewhere that says "some_function(sys.stdout)"?

Comment: I mean - how can I configure it to work with bytes and strings?

Comment: There ase some hacks around `setdefaultencoding` which are basically obsolete but still used in some legacy scripts. If you are on Windows, there's something about waving dead chickens at the crossreads at new moon.

Comment: I'm running on Linux, and can't find it, but I'll try to ask the original developer if he has any idea. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: If standard output is redirected to a file, that could also affect Python's opinion about the file handle. On modern Linux, output to the terminal is typically UTF-8, though it can be configured differently if you need to communicate with equipment from a previous millennium.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `sys.stdout` is always str-typed, with an encoding chosen by the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable (and/or `PYTHONUTF8` on Windows).

[`sys.stdout.buffer` (i.e. a `TextIOBase::buffer`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.buffer) is the underlying bytestream for the text-encoded `stdout` stream.

Since you're reading bytes from the subprocess, you'll need to also write to the byte-typed stream.

```
for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), b''): 
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(c)
```

If, on the other hand, you do expect to be working with text, [you may wish to configure the subprocess object to decode output to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467068/51685).